# the problem with the delegation of zones for creating subdomains Ubuntu VPS DigitalOcean

Tags: dns

I have 3 droplets in digitalocean, I was delegated a zone ex.examle.org and they tied the droplet's IP address to the zone, I set up the nginx configuration for the subdommen n1.ex.examle.org but this site doesn't open. How do I configure dns server to make everything work?

Comment: What _exact_ DNS records did you create? And, what does "this site doesn't open" mean? What error does the browser give?

Comment: By "zone", do you mean load balancer? 

Comment: I created a record of type A (n1.ex.examle.org) and linked it to the IP of another vps